# unable to flash stock rom in swipe elite plus

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, fastboot, bootloader, stock-rom

I'm trying to flash MIUI 8 on my Swipe Elite Plus. It fails and the is device not booting; it's stuck into the Videocon boot logo. After that I successfully flashed the Swipe Elite Plus stock ROM, in my Swipe Elite Plus device, but after rebooting the phone nothing happens, it's again only showing the Videocon logo. I mean stuck over here as happen in the MIUI 8 case as well, instead it shows the setup screen of Swipe Elite Plus, the Videocon logo because I installed the Videocon stock ROM earlier in the device for volte update. What to do now?